# How to unmarshall an element wrapped in another element

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to unmarshall the below XML and extract only a list of `CD` elements from it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Header>
        <SomData>
            <Name>Name</Name>
        </SomData>
    </Header>
    <Message>
        <DziubasekInfo>
            <some_data>Data</some_data>
        </DziubasekInfo>
        <CATALOG>
            <Entry>
                <CD>
                    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
                    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
                    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
                    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
                    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
                    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
                </CD>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <CD>
                    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
                    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
                    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
                    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
                    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
                    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
                </CD>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <CD>
                    <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
                    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
                    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
                    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
                    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
                    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
                </CD>
            </Entry>
        </CATALOG>
    </Message>
</Root>
```

---

This is my actual code that works:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="CATALOG")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Catalog {


    @XmlElement(name = "Entry", type = Entry.class)
    private List<Entry> list = new ArrayList<>();

    .... getters, setters

}
```

---

```
@XmlType(name="Entry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {


    @XmlElement(name = "CD", type = Cd.class)
    private List<Cd> cdList = new ArrayList<>();

    ... getters, setters

}
```

---

```
@XmlType(name="CD")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Cd {

    @XmlElement(name="TITLE")
    private String title;

    @XmlElement(name="ARTIST")
    private String artist;

    @XmlElement(name="PRICE")
    private String price;

    .... getters, setters

}
```

---

```
InputStream inp = getClass().getResourceAsStream("cd_catalog.xml");

XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(inp);

XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);

while (!(xsr.isStartElement() && "CATALOG".equals(xsr.getLocalName()))) {
    xsr.next();
}

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Catalog.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Catalog catalog = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Catalog.class).getValue();

System.out.println("Entries = " + catalog.getList().size());

for (Entry e : catalog.getList()) {
    System.out.format("CD: %20s / %30s / %10s\n",
        e.getCdList().get(0).getArtist(), 
        e.getCdList().get(0).getTitle(), 
        e.getCdList().get(0).getPrice());
}

xsr.close();
```

---

As you see there are 3 classes here: `Catalog` which wraps `Entry` which in turn wraps `Cd` class.
Actually each `Entry` contains only one `Cd` entry.
Is there a way to eliminate one of this wrapper class and use only 2 classes instead of 3 ? 
And and to simplify this code a bit, especially this fragment looks a bit awkward:

```
e.getCdList().get(0).getArtist(), 
e.getCdList().get(0).getTitle(), 
e.getCdList().get(0).getPrice()
```

It's kind of silly to have a list with only one item and always get only this single entry, it would be better to do so:

```
e.getCdList().getArtist(), e.getCdList().getTitle(), e.getCdList().getPrice()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic point for any XML related mappings is not a code, but XML.(actually XML Schema). Your JAXB annotations define the schema. So, if your XML has schema
like you show:

```
<CATALOG>
        <Entry>
            <CD>
                <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
                <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
                <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
                <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
                <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
                <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
            </CD>
        </Entry>
        ...
```

Then it is what it is. Entry element has CD element.
If you'd like to eliminate CD element your XML must look like:

```
<CATALOG>
        <Entry>
                <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
                <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
                <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
                <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
                <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
                <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
        </Entry>
```

No more, no less... Java object (with JAXB annotations) is only reflection of what XML schema dictates. If you cannot change XML - You have to live with that.

BTW: I'm pretty sure that Entry may have other than CD element, like DVD, TAPE, VINIL etc...

Comment: Thank you. I finally solved this problem myself using `@XmlPath(value="Entry/CD")` annotation, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem myself using EclipseLink/Moxy and `@XmlPath(value="Entry/CD")` annotation.
The `Cd` class is the same as in the question.
This is `Catalog` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="CATALOG")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Catalog {

   @XmlElement(name = "CD", type = Cd.class)
   @XmlPath(value="Entry/CD")
   private List<Cd> list = new ArrayList<>();

    ... getters/setters

}
```

---

And here is the code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.context.factory","org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory");

        InputStream inp = getClass().getResourceAsStream("cd_catalog.xml");

        assertTrue(inp != null);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(inp);

        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);

        while (!(xsr.isStartElement() && "CATALOG".equals(xsr.getLocalName()))) {
            xsr.next();
        }

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Catalog.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Catalog catalog = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Catalog.class).getValue();

        System.out.println("Entries = " + catalog.getList().size());

        for (Cd e : catalog.getList()) {
            System.out.format("CD: %20s / %30s / %10s\n", e.getArtist(), e.getTitle(), e.getPrice());
        }

        xsr.close();
```